# What is the solution to detect the change of log data?

Tags: security, logging, software-design

**problem:**

I want to develop a log management system that has the following features:
1- All logs collect from a queue and sequentially add to database
2- The data log can only be added and the system does not allow the user to edit it.
3- If the log data is changed through the database or a log data is deleted, the system must be able to recognize this change.

**my solution:**
I'm serializing the log to Json. Then I calculate the hash(log+ the hash of the previous log) and store it for that log. To detect the change, I repeat this method and compare the calculated hash with the stored hash. If it was different, it indicates a change. But this method sometimes does not work properly. Without any change in the data, a different hash is calculated.

Do you have a better idea?

Answer (score 3):

1.You can save **hash of sum of hash value of each row** in other table and update it when new row has added.

`var hashOfHashes = hash(row1.hash + row2.hash +...);`

2.Other solution for better performance is to prevent deleting row by trigger like this answer [Trigger to prevent Any Deleting from Table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41965222) or [Trigger to prevent Any Deleting from Table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23734892).

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER triggerName
ON tableName
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
  RAISERROR ('Deletion not supported on this table',16,1);
END;
```

If you use Ef Core [this persian post](https://www.dntips.ir/post/3100/%D8%AA%D8%B4%D8%AE%DB%8C%D8%B5-%D8%A7%D8%B5%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA-%D8%B1%D8%AF%DB%8C%D9%81%E2%80%8C%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C-%DB%8C%DA%A9-%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%86%DA%A9-%D8%A7%D8%B7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%AA%DB%8C-%D8%AF%D8%B1-ef-core) can help you.